# warning: already initialized constant Gem::VERSION when running bundle exec rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, gemfile

When in my Rails app I try to run:

```
bundle exec rake -P RAILS_ENV=production
```

I get the following errors:

```
/Users/homm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/gem-0.0.1.alpha/lib/gem.rb:9: warning: already initialized constant Gem::VERSION
/Users/homm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:11: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
/Users/homm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/gem-0.0.1.alpha/lib/gem/requirement.rb:9: warning: already initialized constant Gem::Version::Requirement
/Users/homm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/requirement.rb:269: warning: previous definition of Requirement was here
/Users/homm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/gem-0.0.1.alpha/lib/gem/platform.rb:2: warning: already initialized constant Gem::Platform::RUBY
/Users/homm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/platform.rb:195: warning: previous definition of RUBY was here
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- gem/require
/Users/homm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/gem-0.0.1.alpha/lib/gem.rb:249:in `require'
/Users/homm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/gem-0.0.1.alpha/lib/gem.rb:249:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/homm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/Users/homm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/homm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/Users/homm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/Users/homm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/Users/homm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/Users/homm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
/Users/homm/Projectes/testapp/config/application.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/homm/Projectes/testapp/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/Users/homm/Projectes/testapp/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/homm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/homm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I have the following Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.1.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.0'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :test, :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'gem'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '~> 4.3.1'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.4.1'
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.4.1'
end

gem 'slim', '~> 2.0.3'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.3.0'
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.2"

# Bootstrap
gem 'libv8'
gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails" 
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
```

And I am not sure what is going on. I found this error when trying to push to Heroku, and then I tried to reproduce in my local machine...

Answer (score 0):

Check if you don't have accidentally added this to your Gemfile and **remove it**:

```
gem 'gem'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding `gem 'openssl'` to my Gemfile fixed it (RVM, used autolibs).